# Using Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013 Fortran compilers with Matlab R2011a to create MEX files

Tags: matlab, fortran, intel, mex

I would like to use the Fortran compiler shipped with Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013 to compile MEX files for Matlab.  I currently have Matlab 2011a (32-bit) running on Windows 7 (64-bit), and I am wondering if the XE 2013 version of the Intel compiler will work with this version of Matlab.

Apparently version 13 is the most recent stable release of the Intel Fortran compiler ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Fortran_Compiler)), but R2011a of Matlab only officially supports Intel Fortran version 11.1 ([Mathworks compilers](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win32.html)).

Will more recent versions of the Intel Fortran compiler (such as 13.0) work with R2011a of Matlab (an older version of Matlab), or do I require the *exact* version of the compiler for a successful build?

What combination of compilers could work well?  Might it be possible to only install Intel Fortran version 11.1 using the installer for Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013?

---

There is a blog post that discusses how .stp and .bat files are required for updating the default location used by Matlab for the compiler.  Apparently Matlab scans the `\bin\win32\mexopts` directory for `.stp` and `.bat` files corresponding to each version of the compiler.

http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4064

For my installed version of Matlab, the default location of the Intel compiler appears to be hard-coded:

```
my $default_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Compiler\\11.1\\054\\";
```

So perhaps some of these files need to be slightly updated for each new version of the compiler?  I would assume that only minor changes would be required.

Comment: I doubt there will be any problems with the newest versions. Just try it.

Comment: @VladimirF: OK, thanks Vladimir. I have to purchase the Intel Parallel Studio Suite first.

Comment: No, you can try the evaluation version.

Comment: @VladimirF: Okay, thanks Vladimir; I will try the evaluation version first.  I wonder if the binaries created with the evaluation version of the compiler are time-limited in any way.

Comment: No, the binaries will be fully functional. The evaluation version is meant for serious testing. Anyway, the best place for Intel Fortran questions is http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows

Comment: Sure; that sounds good: thanks Vladimir F.